# Detect Touch and Hold Inside UITableView

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I'm trying to detect touch and hold gestures inside a UITableView, while keeping track of which cell was selected. I need to be able to differentiate between normal taps on a cell and touches that last longer than X seconds (probably 1s or so). The main challenge is that I'd like to do this without subclassing UITableViewCell, since doing so slowed down my scrolling significantly. I think there's probably a way to do this using an NSTimer, but I can't seem to get it working correctly. Using touchesBegan: and touchesEnded: with a timer is out, since I don't see any way to keep track of which cell was selected, unless there's some way to do that with those methods? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For OS 3.2 or later, you can use UILongPressGestureRecognizer.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3924446/long-press-on-uitableview/3924965#3924965.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

UILongPressGestureRecognizer is made for exactly this thing. You an create one and add it to the UITableViewCell to handle long pressses.

Comment: This is perfect, I didn't realize this even existed and didn't see it in the documentation. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 18):

If we are talking about cells, you may want to get the indexPath of the cell that has been pressed.

Add the gesture recognizer to the cell, right after a new instance has been allocated:

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleLongPress:)];
[cell addGestureRecognizer:longPress];
[longPress release];
```

Handle the long press event, and get the indexPath:

```
-(void) handleLongPress: (UIGestureRecognizer *)longPress {
    if (longPress.state==UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        CGPoint pressPoint = [longPress locationInView:table];
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [table indexPathForRowAtPoint:pressPoint];
    }
}
```

Comment: It may be slightly better to add recognizer to cell.contentView, otherwise it will interfere with edit mode.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: Subclass and use a `UILongPressGestureRecognizer`.

Longer answer: I believe the reason you are having scrolling issues with your `UITableViewCell` subclass is that the `reuseIdentifier` is not matching and so cells aren't being reused.  Make sure the `reuseIdentifier` that you are using in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method matches the `reuseIdentifier` that you are setting in Interface Builder for the custom `UITableViewCell` nib.  I had the same problem when I made my first subclass and just matching the `reuseIdentifier` made everything better. :)

As far as using a `UILongPressGestureRecognizer`, take a look at the documentation for `UIGestureRecognizer`s and you should be able to figure it out pretty quickly.

[`UILongPressGestureRecognizer` Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UILongPressGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

[`UIGestureRecognizer` Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not using IB for anything, everything is created programmatically. The problem is a known one, where adding multiple subviews to a cell without custom drawing slows down scrolling dramatically. So I ended up just avoiding subclassing and just "dumbing down" my table view cells and custom drawing/placing pieces of the cell without adding subviews and everything scrolls smoothly.