# select UITableView cell with uitableviewcellselectionstylenone

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I set uitableviewcellselectionstylenone on cells when I created cell. On long press I need to select exact cell, is it posible to do?

Comment: You could add a gesture recogniser, or create a custom cell which doesn't draw the blue highlight on tap but still sends the "did select" delegate call.

Answer (score 1):

Add a `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` to the table. You can find out the cell on which the user long-pressed by calling `indexPathForRowAtPoint`.

```
CGPoint p = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:self.myTableView];
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.myTableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:p];
```

See [the accepted answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3924446/long-press-on-uitableview) for a complete example.

Comment: You can also use `[self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell]` to get the index path

Comment: @hypercrypt But I do not have a cell in the callback of the gesture recognizer: all it gives me is a point of the touch.