# Gestures on a UICollectionViewCell; what to do with the result?

Tags: objective-c, ios6, uicollectionview

I'm currently working on a project for an iPad app. The main screen is a `UICollectionView` with `AlbumCell`'s, a subclass of `UICollectionViewCell`. Now I wanted to add an `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` to pop up an `UIActionSheet`.

First I tried that in the `UICollectionViewController`, but I figured that that isn't the right place to add those. So my best guess is adding the gesture in the `AlbumCell` class? Then probably adding itself as delegate, so it catches it's own gestures.

Is this a good approach so far?

After I catch the gesture, I should show the `UIActionSheet`. Now I open it in the `UICollectionViewController` when the user selects a cell while in editing mode. But should I call a method on the `UICollectionViewController` to open it, like I do now? Or should the cell handle it's own `UIActionSheet`?

Eventually I got to let the `UICollectionViewController` what to do, might be to let him open the `UIActionSheet`, or handle accordingly to the result of it. How should the `AlbumCell` "communicate" with it?

It's something I've been struggling with multiple times, not just in this use case. Is the approach close, or should I handle those actions totally different?

Comment: As AlbumCell is a view, and UICollectionViewController is a view controller. So "open the UIActionSheet" action should be managed by UICollectionViewController. You can use [Protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Protocol.html)/[Delegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#Documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Delegation.html).

Comment: That makes sense. But the recognized should be added to the cell subclass?

Comment: Yep, as the cell will be reused.

Comment: Okay. All clear so far, but how should I let the view controller know that one of the cells was pressed, and which one?

Comment: You can create an iVar like index as a tag for your cell.

Comment: If I add the `UIGestureRecognizer` to the `AlbumCell`, with the delegate to `self`. I should somehow tell the `UICollectionViewController` to do something with the `Album` that belongs to the `AlbumCell`.

Comment: Actually, i think you don't need to add the index iVar either, the pressed cell will response you action (through controller).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can adopt the same method of [using `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` on `UITableView`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3924446/long-press-on-uitableview).

Basically, set up *one* recognizer. In the selector, use the `indexPathForItemAtPoint:` to find out what index path the user was pressing on. Finally, if the user is pressing on a cell (and not pressing on the space in between cells), present the `UIActionSheet` however you like.

Comment: Of course, why didn't I think about that myself? I knew it wasn't really the way it should be, this makes a lot more sense! Gonna implement that, pretty sure it'll do the job. :)