# UITableViewCell with multiple gestures: long-press and tap

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

As the question states, I would like to implement two different actions for a tap and a long-press on a UITableViewCell.

I reckon I have to deselect the row at each stage and put no functions inside here:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
}
```

And then add Tap Gestures from storyboard, but Storyboard give me an error when I drag actions to prototype cells. Hints?

Answer (score 14):

try this -

In your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method, you can add tap gesture and long press gesture separately and then implement them. By this your `didselect` function will not be required and you wont have to `deSelect` anything.

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(cellTapped:)];
    tapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    tapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
    cell.tag = indexPath.row;
    [cell addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizer];


UILongPressGestureRecognizer *lpgr = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc]
                         initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleLongPress:)];
        lpgr.minimumPressDuration = 1.0; //seconds
        [cell addGestureRecognizer:lpgr];

cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
```

Now,

```
-(void)handleLongPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)longPress
{
    // Your code here
}

-(void)cellTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)tap
{
    // Your code here
}
```

Comment: hi this is working for me,, but its going to execute this handleLongpress method two times,, I create the gesture and added it into the cell withing cellAtIndex  method

Comment: It should be done in cellForRowAtIndexPath as stated above. It should not call the same method twice

Comment: For `UILongPressGestureRecognizer ` you should always check the status property because otherwise you may get numerous calls. e.g.: `recognizer.state==UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan`

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the single tap action with the method of UITableViewDelegate you posted above,

`- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

for doing a UILongPressGestureRecognizer on your UITableViewCell [follow this instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3924965/1363634).

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift**:

> Define Gestures like this:

```
fileprivate func addGestures(inCell cell: UITableViewCell, withIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer.init(target: self, action: #selector(cellTapped))
    tapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    tapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1
    cell.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)

    let lpgr = UILongPressGestureRecognizer.init(target: self, action: #selector(cellLongPressed))
    lpgr.minimumPressDuration = 1.0
    cell.addGestureRecognizer(lpgr)

    cell.tag = indexPath.row

    cell.selectionStyle = .none
}

@objc fileprivate func cellTapped(_ gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
     //Do whatever you want to!
}

@objc fileprivate func cellLongPressed(_ gesture: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    if gesture.state == .began {
         //Do whatever you want to!
    }
}
```

> And add gesture like this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = (tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CellIdentifier") as! UITableViewCell)

    self.addGestures(inCell: cell, withIndexPath: indexPath)
}
```