# How do you get the indexPath of the cell you are tapping?

Tags: ios, uitableview, ibaction, nsindexpath

I am trying to execute an IBAction when a long-press is performed on a cell in a UITableView. The action involves the content of the cell so I need to get the indexPath in order to retrieve the content from a dictionary in local storage. The IBAction method is defined in the MasterViewController.m file which contains the UITableView methods and is subclassed from UITableViewController. I have tried all of the following, and they all return null instead of the indexPath for the cell.

```
UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)self;
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];

NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:sender];

NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
```

I have also seen a few years-old answers to similar questions that use the position of the cell in the view, but I can't get any of those to work either.

**UPDATE:**
The IBAction, sendToPB, is being defined in a subclass of UITableViewController.  There is a long-press gesture recognizer added to the cell in Interface Builder, with Sent Actions connected to sendToPB.  The action is supposed to be copying the content of the cell to the clipboard when you long-press on the cell in the table view.  All the ways I have tried so far return null for indexPath.

```
- (IBAction)sendToPB:(id)sender {
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:sender];
    NSString *object = self.objects[indexPath.row];
    UIPasteboard *pb = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
    NSString *pressedCellText = [[Data getAllNotes] objectForKey:object];
    [pb setString: pressedCellText];
}
```

**UPDATE:**
I have found two problems with this approach.  First, the long-press gesture doesn't actually select the row, which is why all of the options that used `indexPathForSelectedRow` don't work.  Second, `sender` is the gesture recognizer, and not the cell or row, so using `sender` also produces a null value for `indexPath`.  With these two factors in mind, how else can you detect which cell you performed the long-press on?

Comment: when you debug, what type of object does self seem to be? You cast it as a table cell but then you also call self.tableView like it's a view controller.

Comment: Add the code snippet for add the long gestures to the cell

Comment: You need to show more code. Show how the long press is setup and handled.

Comment: Please see my answer below and try NSIndexPath *indexPath = self.tableview.indexPathForSelectedRow Then breakpoint and report the values of indexPath and object.

Comment: @Spectravideo328 indexPath is null, and object is 2014-11-02 13:24:38 +0000 (the key of the first cell in the table).  So no matter which cell you press on, because indexPath is null, you always get the content of the first cell, row 0, sent to the clipboard.

Comment: @ChiliOcean You still haven't told us what `sender` is in your `sendToPB:` method. It's probably not the cell.

Comment: @rmaddy The gesture recognizer is attached to the cell, so doesn't that make the cell the sender?

Comment: @ChiliOcean No, it probably makes the gesture recognizer the sender. Why don't you check using the debugger.

Comment: @maddy You were correct that sender is the gesture recognizer.

Comment: @ChiliOcean you can get cell from gesture recognisers view property like this `UITableViewCell *cell=(UITableViewCell*)recogniser.view ` and you can then get index path easily

Answer (score 2):

Declare variable 1st in .h file as

```
 NSIndexPath *hitIndex;
```

then on long press method u can get the position of cell & hence indexpath

```
(void)longPressMethod:(UIButton *)btn
{

CGPoint hitPoint = [btn convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:tbl_traits];
hitIndex = [tbl_traits indexPathForRowAtPoint:hitPoint];

}
```

Comment: What is `tbl_traits`? Why does `hitIndex` need to an ivar? And which .h file do you mean?

Comment: tbl_trait is the object of tableview & hitIndex is the NSIndexPath object so that u can get the contents of cell using hitIndex.row & .h is the simple controllers .h file to declare varible.

Comment: Where in the OP's question is there a mention of `tbl_traits` and a "simple controller"? Your answer is confusing and out of context.

Comment: simple controller is just the controller in which u have added tableview & tbl_trait is the object of tableview for which longpress gesture method will be there,u can add this method as follow:

        UILongPressGestureRecognizer *lpgr = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] 
  initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longPressMethod:)];
lpgr.minimumPressDuration = 2.0; //seconds
lpgr.delegate = self;
[self. tbl_traits addGestureRecognizer:lpgr];
[lpgr release];

Answer (score 2):

You can get indexPath Like This on longPressGesture!

```
-(void)handleLongPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
     CGPoint p = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:self.myTableView];

     NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.myTableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:p];
     if (indexPath == nil) {
         NSLog(@"long press on table view but not on a row");
     } 
     else if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) 
     {

         NSLog(@"long press on table view at row %d", indexPath.row);
     } 
     else 
     {
         NSLog(@"gestureRecognizer.state = %d", gestureRecognizer.state);
     }
}
```

may Be this Link will help you a little [more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3924446/long-press-on-uitableview)

Comment: Don't just copy a chunk out of another answer. This is a comment at best.

Comment: yeah but i also put that link from where i copied and user just need indexpath so i copied it!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using Gesture Recognizers. Hope these snippets help.......

In your `.h file`

```
@interface yourClass ()
{
    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPressRecognizer;
}
```

In viewDidLoad,

```
longPressRecognizer = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longPressDetected:)];
longPressRecognizer.minimumPressDuration = 2;
longPressRecognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
longPressRecognizer.delegate = self;
```

In cellForRowAtIndexPath, just before `return` statement

```
[cell addGestureRecognizer:longPressRecognizer];
```

And at the end,

```
- (void) longPressDetected:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)recognizer 
{
    UITableViewCell *selectedCell = (UITableViewCell *)recognizer.view;
    // Your required code here
}
```

Comment: It is very unethical to downvote someone else's answer on the same question you are answering. It shows you are doing this to promote your answer. It is the OP or other viewers of this QA who should upvote or downvote.

Comment: Okay, I'm sorry if that's the case. I'm fairly new to SO. Can you please provide me a proper link for rules or such? I take back my downvote.

Comment: No sweat. We were all new one day!

Comment: Thanks! Still, any link to rules or guidelines would be much helpful.

Comment: You've done nothing wrong, and meta stack overflow is the best place to find out about rules and so forth.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Thanks to @RegularExpression

First be sure to set the delegate of your **tableView**

```
self.myTableView.delegate = self
```

I believe this is what you are looking for:

> Swift

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    //save the indexPath.row as an integer inside a property or pass it to your action
}
```

You can then save the index of from the above method or simple call your action passing that index inside the above method.

> Objective-C

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

       //save the indexPath.row as an integer inside a property or pass it to your action
}
```

Comment: But please be sure you have your delegate set.

Comment: I don't think this works if you are trying to determine if a long press has occurred without a touch up inside.

Answer (score 0):

If this is inside a UITableViewController subclass, then casting self (which is an instance of the UITableViewController subclass) to UITableViewCell will not return the cell selected.

There is really 2 ways of doing this:

1- The easy way: Don't use an IBAction and just implement the delegate methods:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

2- The relatively easy way: in your IBaction, you can get the selected cell by using the property:

```
self.tableview.indexPathForSelectedRow
```

This property will give you the indexpath of the selected cell.

Comment: The user wants to detect long press. Sorry dude, -1 for this.

Comment: @LibranCoder I think you are confused on the rules of downvoting. I suggest your review them. The OP's question is how to determine the cell that was selected and not how to create the long press gesture recognizer.

Comment: I'm sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: @librancoder is right, the question is about detecting which cell was long-pressed, not which is the selected cell. and there's nothing wrong with down voting other answers to questions you're answering! If you read a question, see an answer you think is wrong and have an answer you think is right, why wouldn't you downvote?

Comment: @LibranCoder I think if we allow downvoting in the interest of self-promotion (or not) to propagate, the SO community will not be able to tell the difference between a downvoted answer based on the quality versus self promotion. My 2 cents...

Answer (score 0):

If you attached the `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` to the `cell` by calling `cell.addGestureRegognizer(_: _: _:)` you should retrieve the cell from the sender by doing

```
let touchedView = sender.view as! UITableViewCell
```

Anyway, the best way to achieve this usually is by inspecting the dataSource instead of calling the `UITableViewDataSource` methods

Answer (score -1):

You could subclass UITableViewCell and add an IVar for the index path and set that when cellForRowAtIndexPath is called for the UITableView dataSource protocol.