# iPhone: How to find out which object was touched

Tags: iphone

On my UIViewController I have different UIViews, and some of them are my custom UIViews. How to know which UIView was touched, my custom or not ??

Comment: You might find your answer here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793242/detect-if-certain-uiview-was-touched-amongst-other-uiviews

Comment: try isKindOfClass method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set tag to each of your view.

```
view1.tag = y;
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = 
    [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self 
                                            action:@selector(singleTapGestureCaptured:)];
tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
[view1 addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
```

and in `singleTapGestureCaptured` method:

```
- (void)singleTapGestureCaptured:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{ 
    [[gesture view] tag];
    NSLog(@"tap captured for view :%d", [[gesture view] tag]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create two [UIGestureRecognizers](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html)  then you have to associate the gesture recognizer with your views like this:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer * recognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];
[view addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];

UITapGestureRecognizer * recognizerCustom = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTapCustom:)];
[customView addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
```

This way you know when the `handleTap`: method is called your normal view was touched and when your `handleTapCustom`: gets called your custom view was called.