# Detect when a drag enters a UIView

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview, drag, uitouch

I'd like to recognize when a user places their finger on one `UIView`, drags to another `UIView`, and releases. These views can be in arbitrary positions in the same superview, and there can be any number of them.

This seems like it should be a simple task but it looks like Apple has made it harder than necessary. All the `touchesMoved`, `touchDragEnter`, and so on only work for touches that originate in the view in question. I have seen solutions that involve intercepting the touch in the superview, but I have a number of subviews in the superview that do not require this functionality, so I'd like to avoid intercepting touches in the superview if possible.

Is there any reasonably simple way to detect a touch that drags from elsewhere into a `UIView`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793242/detect-if-certain-uiview-was-touched-amongst-other-uiviews

Comment: Can you put the gesture on the containing view and just detect when that enters/leaves the various subviews?