# I have UIViewController. And UIView inside How detect touchs independently?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, touch, uitouch

**I have UIViewController. And 3 UIView inside  How detect touchs independently.**

I have 3 classes, and added the objects in the UIViewController

And have this method in each class, I need touch the object (UIView) responds to the event independently

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

}
```

example:

- view1  NSLog(@"I Touched View 1");

  view2  NSLog(@"I Touched View 2");

  view3  NSLog(@"I Touched View 3");

Thanks!!

Comment: I think I understood correctly your problem now, if that would not be the case, please be more precise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If all of the three views are descendant of your viewController's view, you could use the following code snippet

```
for (UITouch *t in touches) {
    CGPoint p = [t locationInView:self.view];
    UIView *v = [self.view hitTest:p withEvent:event];
    NSLog(@"touched view %@", v);
}
```

**EDIT**

Ok, I supposed you had only one entry entry point (into the `UIViewController`) for  touch detection of your subviews; If, like you said, you have a class for each subview, you have already solved your problem. You don't need to do anything else other than put your `NSLog(@"touched..")` code inside each `touchBegan:withEvent:` method.

E.g.

```
@implementation FirstSubview
.
.
-( void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    NSLog(@"I touched View 1");
}
.
.
@end
```

*Note*: Since the `UIViewController` is also a `UIResponder` (i.e, inherits from `UIResponder`) you can also use the first solution I posted.

Comment: also, try to take a look at [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793242/detect-if-certain-uiview-was-touched-amongst-other-uiviews?rq=1)

Comment: thanks... this works very well!

But when touches UIView 1, how can i do to the event is captured by the father? it's possible??

For example 

Touch UIView 1 and the (father) "set" viewcontroller.alpha=0

Sorry for my english...

Comment: there are several way to do that, you could use, e.g, the first solution I mentioned or call back the view controller through a delegate (see [link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/DelegatesandDataSources/DelegatesandDataSources.html)) or use the more standard approach which basically consists on adding to your `UIButton`s a target\action through `-addTarget:action:forControlEvent` (see [link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Target-Action/Target-Action.html))