# UIControlEventTouchUpInside in custom UIView

Tags: ios, uiview, uitouch

The following function is applied to a set of UIViews.  Rather than have the color change upon finishing a touch, I would like for it to only change the color if the user touches up inside of the view.  Therefore it is still possible for the user to drag their finger outside of the view and thus the method will not fire.

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"o_tile.png"]];
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detect if certain UIView was touched amongst other UIViews](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793242/detect-if-certain-uiview-was-touched-amongst-other-uiviews)

Comment: I am not concerned with which UIView is touched.  I am using fast enumeration to detect which view by tag.  I only want to detect a touch within a UIView when the user touches up inside.

Comment: Yes, I understand your original post.  I posted that other answer since they show how to convert the touch point and check if that point is within the rect of a given view.  Then you can check if the touch up occurred within a certain UIView.