# Detect when a view is tapped on

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6

I have multiple Views inside a ViewController and I want to know when a view is tapped on and I'm not sure how to go about it

Comment: I assume this is iOS, however the term "clicked" implies the use of a mouse.  Please edit your tags.

Comment: In iOS things are tapped. There is nothing to click.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detect if certain UIView was touched amongst other UIViews](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793242/detect-if-certain-uiview-was-touched-amongst-other-uiviews)

Comment: Yeah could be, had trouble finding an answer

Answer (score 0):

In order to check whether certain view inside another view was touched you can use hitTest.

```
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
```

In your custom implementation of touchesBegan check every touch in touches set. The point for hitTest method can be obtained using

```
- (CGPoint)locationInView:(UIView *)view;
method, where the view is your superView (the one that contains other views).
```

EDIT: Here's a fast custom implementation:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event { 
    CGPoint locationPoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];
    UIView* viewYouWishToObtain = [self hitTest:locationPoint withEvent:event];
}
```

I hope this was helpful, Paul

Sources : [Detect if certain UIView was touched amongst other UIViews](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793242/detect-if-certain-uiview-was-touched-amongst-other-uiviews)